# Code Complete: Stack Overflow edition?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, best-practices

Apologies in advance if this has already been covered, but the similar-looking questions I found here didn't quite cover the area I'd like to.

I've been reading a lot lately, and like a lot of folks I've been using StackOverflow as sort of a supplement. For example, I was reading a section on defining visibility for object members and methods, and I wanted a bit more information on where the `protected` visibility comes into play. I had a vague recollection of having seen other articles saying that `protected` is an abomination, so I went digging on StackOverflow.

This gave me the idea that with all the collected knowledge on this site, we have one hell of a "best practices" book lurking below the surface. It would be nice if we could somehow nominate particular questions (perhaps particular answers) as being particularly helpful to someone just starting out. This idea is part of the reason that I actually liked the old [subjective] and [best-practices] tags, because it made this sort of thing browseable, but I understand why these tags were killed.

I think "sort by votes" isn't necessarily the right answer, because you get a lot of decent theory questions (like my example above) which don't receive perhaps as much exposure as perhaps they should and therefore don't receive lots of votes.

You could also say that you could just also filter by a specific tag, but I don't think that addresses the ["unknown unknowns"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There_are_known_knowns) - beginners really don't know what they don't know, and so can't ask or even find the sorts of questions containing information that would be extremely valuable to them.

I don't know how to address this problem, but one idea would be to flag a question as a good theory question and have these questions appear on some sort of FAQ page where folks could view/group them. A sort of crowdsourced version of Code Complete.

Thoughts?

Comment: **Stack Complete:** *A schizophrenic handbook of software construction*

Comment: Hum, may be difficult to handle, but good idea (sorry for the temporary downvote. I misclicked the star)

Comment: Just abandoned a long rambling answer, which is possibly indicative of the problems of crowdsourcing - or more probably indicative of the strength of the drink in the pub I've just left.  Hic.

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen this?

[Stack Overflow ebooks for Kindle](https://stackapps.com/questions/2035/stack-overflow-ebooks-for-kindle)